# Direct search for a key-value pair in redis

Tags: redis

In a redis-cli session:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET somekey "Greetings"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> SET somekey "Mortal"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> EXISTS somekey
(integer) 1
```

I am looking for a function SOMEFUNC that searches for a key *and* a value. Perhaps something such as:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SOMEFUNC "somekey:Greetings"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> SOMEFUNC "somekey:Ave"
(integer) 0
```

It's all driven by a program, so I could use SSCAN on the key and compare, but I'm wondering if there is SOMEFUNC that will do this directly, as the statements above illustrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @MrWiggles, there is no such `SOMEFUNC` for Strings. On top of the two alternatives that he suggests, another that could get you pretty close is using Hashes instead. Consider the following:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET somehash "Greetings" ""
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HEXISTS somehash "Greetings"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HEXISTS somehash "Mortal"
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> HEXISTS someotherhash "Ave"
(integer) 0
```

Sets can also do the same trick:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD someset "Greetings"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> SISMEMBER someset "Greetings"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> SISMEMBER someset "Mortal"
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> SISMEMBER someotherset "Ave"
(integer) 0
```

That said, note that Hashes & Sets have memory overheads (just like Strings). For 100,000 String/Hash/Set keys, here's what my local Redis' `INFO MEMRORY` reports for `used_memory(_human)`:

- Strings: 9594616 (9.15M)
- Hashes: 11194616 (10.68M)
- Sets: 25594616 (24.1M)

The real question, however, is why you want to keep everything in separate keys. Unless there's a compelling reason not to do so in your use case, consider a single Hash as a mini-store for all of your "keys" (fields) and values, e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET minikv somekey Greetings
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET minikv anotherkey Human
(integer) 1
...
```

In terms of your original question, this will bring you back to square one - meaning you'll have to read (`HGET minikv somekey`) and compare in your app or, my favorite, wrap it in Lua to do it in one call, perhaps like this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "return redis.call('HGET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == ARGV[2] and 1 or 0" 1 minikv somekey Greetings
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "return redis.call('HGET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == ARGV[2] and 1 or 0" 1 minikv somekey Mortal
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "return redis.call('HGET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == ARGV[2] and 1 or 0" 1 minikv anotherkey Mortal
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "return redis.call('HGET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == ARGV[2] and 1 or 0" 1 minikv anotherkey Human
(integer) 1
```

The nice thing about using this `minikv` Hash is the footprint - a 100K Hash `INFO memory`:

```
used_memory:8519088
used_memory_human:8.12M
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in to Redis that will do this for you.

A couple of ways of achieving this are:

1. Fetch the value of the key back into your application and then check the value to see if it equals what you want it to
2. Use a Lua script to do this on the redis server